# How do I block proxy sites from copying my site?

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I have a site and I see that there are proxies which are messing up my seo, what I mean it's not that someone connects through proxy, but there are domains that when you go to it's EXACTLY like my site, even if I upload something to my ftp I can access it from the other site. I want to block all access from other domains to my content, blocking IP one by one is too hard, someone is making proxies all the time and they change IP every time. So what I want is that the site can only be accessed if in browser url there is my site name (example.com/mypage not proxy.com/mypage which shows same content except all occurrences of my site names are replaced)
Here is my current htaccess code. I'm using nginx as reverse proxy

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^inc/.*$ index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(ico|css|png|jpg|gif|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Are you really sure those are proxies? That would be highly untypical. Usually sites are copied, not proxied. And you cannot really block anyone from copying your site, since you published it.

Comment: If those really are proxies, then you want to examine those requests headers to see if you can find a pattern that identifies auch a proxy.

Comment: I'm sure they are proxies. My site is somewhat secured, even if I change my mysql passwords the other sites get the same errors. Or if I turn off apache or nginx, those sites are offline too

Comment: Then quite frankly I see little point in blocking, since that won't harm you. You claim those proxies "are messing up my seo" - how so?

Comment: My seo title is like this (in google): Bla bla bla - mysite.com
when you type in google site:mysite.com on links to my site there is Bla bla bla - cuckoldmommycheryl.com ... and other really weird names. Also my site deranked on google really fking fast and really hard and since then when I type site:mysite.com links to my pages have those weird names.

Comment: It's exactly this. https://blog.sucuri.net/2016/04/cloned-website-stealing-google-rankings-seo-serp.html and I can't do anything about it.

Comment: The first half of your statement two comments above is without meaning for you - and you simply cannot change that. About your site "deranking"... I don't see how that should be caused by such proxies, considering how the ranking algorithm works, by maybe I am wrong there.

Comment: Anyway, as already said above: you want to check if you can find a pattern to identify such proxies based in headers in their requests. Also cross site request forgery protection tokens might come in handy here, since proxies most likely won't be able to handle those for follow up pages.

Comment: Headers don't look like they have any patterns. The problem is that the site is doing something like this -> curl my site content -> get it to html -> change all of "mysite.com" to "theirsite.com" -> delete all <script>s -> render
So htaccess blocking domain doesn't work nor any other think except from directly blocking the IP, but they're changing the IP's everyday.

Comment: I doubt those proxies use something like `cURL`, that would be a huge effort. More likely they simply use either the proxy module builtin to http servers or a real proxy. Anyway, you should be able to detect that. But even so - if those proxies really block javascript then my previous hint to the tokens should, work like charm.

Comment: Nothing we can do, only you have access to those details.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can detect bots requests by googling random strings from your site, then follow links, then look into logs. Then block those ips.
2. You can enable some kind of javascript protection on your site. Detect current address/host then compare to yours. Redirect false to your domain.

Use imagination and patterns.